# Failed to bind request element. Spring meb mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, controller, http-status-code-400

Здравствуйте, при попытке изменить запись выскакивет ошибка :

tomcat - `HTTP Status [400] – [Bad Request]`

```
 WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "update"
 WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "update"
```

update.jsp:

```
 <form:form action="update" method="post" commandName="word">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="russWord">Русское Слово
                        </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="russWord"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="englishWord">Английское Слово
                        </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="englishWord"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Ok"
                        onclick="/Words/" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
  </form:form>
```

---

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void update(Word word) {
    service.updateWord(word);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/updateWord/{id}")
public String updateWord(@PathVariable("id")int id, Model model) {
    Word word = service.getForId(id);
    model.addAttribute("word", word);
    return "update";
}
```

Класс Word:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "words")
    public class Word {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "WordID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int wordId;
        @Column(name = "russWord")
        private String russWord;
        @Column(name = "englishWord")
        private String englishWord;
        //getters and setters   
 }
```

что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: что, совесем нет мыслей ни у кого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spring пытается конвертировать обьект с реквеста в Word в методе

```
 public void update(Word word)
```

в реквесте все приходит как стрин и только на уровне спринга идет конвертация в нужные типы. 
судя по

> type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'

какое то поле имеет тип int примитив , лучше юзать Integer , потому как Integer может быть null , а у int если значение не определенно то дефолтное 0 а если передано 0 тот как отличить от того что ничего не было передано ...

есть еще варианты  [так](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-custom-converter/) и [так](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-creating-a-custom-handlermethodargumentresolver/) .